# Multi-Tenant Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, servicebus

We are building multi-tenant microservices based platform on Azure and we are using service bus for integration between micro-services.

We are receiving input pipeline message from batch and real-time and I want to ensure all tenant message process with equal priority.

pipeline looks like

[image]

Note: we are using Azure function to process service-bus messages

below line I got from Microsoft documentation

> This fully managed service is available in multi or single tenant
>   configurations with no servers to manage or licenses to buy.

Can anyone suggest, How to use service bus in multi-tenant scenario? do you think I really need to care if I'm using azure function (azure function will auto scale)?
**I want to give equal priority to all tenant.**

Comment: I guess they mean you as tenant. You may use Service Bus Standard tier where you'll share resources with other Azure customers, or Premium tier where you'll get your dedicated instance of Service Bus. What does your "equal priority" requirement entitle?

Comment: @Mikhail Can you please refer some doc link

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-premium-messaging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Mikhail, I confused by below statement

> This fully managed service is available in multi or single tenant
>   configurations with no servers to manage or licenses to buy.

Azure ServiceBus Standard run under shared resources while premium runs a dedicated instance of Service Bus.

[image]

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-premium-messaging) for more details